# Bootstrap responsive tables inside responsive tabs

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Using [footable](http://fooplugins.com/plugins/footable-jquery/) inside of [Boostrap Responsive Tabs](http://openam.github.io/bootstrap-responsive-tabs/) and have an issue after resize. If you load the page on a desktop everything works as expected until you resize your screen. As soon as you resize your screen the tables within the tabs no longer function. This works both ways where as if you load the page with your browser window shrank the tables will work inside the responsive tabs, but when you expand the window they break.

Have reproduced the issue in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yvj106zb/39/embedded/result/)

(External resources can be found on fiddle)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    fakewaffle.responsiveTabs(['xs']);
    $('.footable').footable();

});

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12"> 
    <div class="bs-component">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs responsive">
            <li class="active">
                <a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">This</a>
            </li>
            <li>    
                <a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Is</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">My</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab4">Boomstick!</a>
            </li>
         </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade active in">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover footable toggle-medium">
                    <thead>
                         <th>Identifier</th>
                         <th data-hide="all">Column2</th>
                         <th data-hide="all">Column3</th>
                     </thead>
                     <tbody>
                         <tr>
                             <td>Clickme</td>
                             <td>Okay</td>
                             <td>Whatever</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                             <td>Second Row</td>
                             <td>Still Okay</td>
                             <td>Still Whatever</td>
                          </tr>
                     </tbody>
                 </table>
             </div>
             <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade active">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover footable toggle-medium">
                    <thead>
                         <th>Identifier</th>
                         <th data-hide="all">Column2</th>
                         <th data-hide="all">Column3</th>
                     </thead>
                     <tbody>
                         <tr>
                             <td>Clickme</td>
                             <td>Okay</td>
                             <td>Whatever</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                             <td>Second Row</td>
                             <td>Still Okay</td>
                             <td>Still Whatever</td>
                          </tr>
                     </tbody>
                 </table>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue occurs because when "Boostrap Responsive Tabs" change the display mode (tab or accordion), it removes all the HTML content from your tab and appends it to the accordion and vice-versa.
So javascript event used by footable are removed to.

In order to make it works, you have to re-initialize footable on resize each time "Boostrap Responsive Tabs" change the display mode.

```
var panelView = $('.panel-group.responsive').is(':visible');    
$( window ).resize( function () {
    if ( $('.panel-group.responsive').is(':visible') != panelView ) {
        $('.footable').removeClass('footable-loaded').footable();
        panelView = $('.panel-group.responsive').is(':visible');
    }
} );
```

live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/us7hgf3g/